# comparision of date in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to compare particular date with today to know whether that paricular date is greater than today

Thanks Harish.

Comment: o_o. Quite the varied tag set there, eh?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 12):

```
@date = "2010-07-20".to_date # 20th July
@today=Date.today # 21st July

if @date >= @today
  puts "@date is greater than or equal to today's date"
else
  puts "@date is less than today's date"  
end
```

O/P

```
@date is less than today's date
```

Comment: Simple as always with ruby

Answer (score 5):

`date` object has `future?` and `past?` methods. It's the best way I can think of.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using date objects, you just compare as expected.

```
date1 > date2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do something like:

```
class Integer
  def minutes
    self * 60
  end
  def hours
    self * 60.minutes
  end
  def days
    self * 24.hours
  end
  def weeks
    self * 7.days
  end
  def months #can probably be more accurate, but I'll just use 30.days
    self * 30.days
  end
  def years
    self * 12.months
  def
end
```

If I had to deal a  lot with `Time`s. Now you can do something like

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = t1 + 1.days
puts "You're in the past~" if t1 < t2
```

I am assuming that's what Rails does anyway.