# Checking if date is over a day old, over a year old etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What would the best way be to check if a date is more than a day old, or a year old etc?

Answer (score 12):

See this question: [comparision of date in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296539/comparision-of-date-in-ruby)
The compare to a value like

```
1.day.ago
1.month.ago
1.year.ago
```

Using these produces the following output:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > 1.year.ago
 => Thu, 27 May 2010 17:45:25 UTC +00:00 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > 1.month.ago
 => Wed, 27 Apr 2011 17:45:32 UTC +00:00 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > 1.day.ago
 => Thu, 26 May 2011 17:45:36 UTC +00:00 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 >
```

and see if that works.

Answer (score 7):

Use ActiveSupport helpers

```
@date < 1.day.ago

@some_other_date < 2.years.ago
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if the_date < 1.day.ago or the_date < 1.year.ago
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a_date > 1.day.ago
a_date > 1.year.ago
```

Comment: Careful, recent Date is greater than older date, e.g. `1.day.ago > 1.month.ago`

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6 now has [more idiomatic Time comparitors](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32185) that you can use:

```rb
date.before?(1.day.ago)
date.after?(1.week.ago)
```

Which I think is much nicer that the standard comparison operators.

As Jan Klimo mentions in a comment above, you'd naturally read `last_login > 1.month.ago` as "`last_login` is more than 1 month ago", which is the exact opposite of what it means.

`before?` and `after?` allows you to avoid that extra mental hop when parsing it.